# How to define a global gsl_vector

Tags: c, gsl

Could someone help me with this problem? I have this simple code:

```
#include "prova.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_pow_int.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>

/* Global structures */
#define LENGTH_Cell 1001
gsl_vector * Cell; /* Global definition */

/* Function */
double sum(int l){
    double sum = 0;

    for(int j=0; j<l; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + gsl_vector_get(Cell, j);
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() {

    gsl_vector * Cell = gsl_vector_alloc(LENGTH_Cell);

    FILE *Cl_in = fopen("C_ells_1000.dat","r");
    gsl_vector_fscanf(Cl_in, Cell);
    fclose(Cl_in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("sum: %g \n", sum(i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles, however when I run the program gives the following output:

```
sum: 0 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I think the problem is that I haven't defined in the correct way the global gsl_vector Cell. 
Do you have any suggestion?

Some more informations. 
Here's the content of "C_ells_1000.dat"

```
0.
0.
1.48889036806174737e-10
6.99975015453780434e-11
3.9538692950311228e-11
2.51360836766398574e-11
1.73497511436282967e-11
1.27165467072195804e-11
9.75002071723029932e-12
7.7432773162174558e-12
6.3213378366797444e-12
5.27764322481988366e-12
```

While the file "prova.h" is the following:

```
#ifndef prova_h
#define prova_h

#include <stdio.h>

#endif /* prova_h */
```

To compile the programm I use the command

```
gcc -o prova prova_1.c -I /usr/local/include -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: For a complete question you should also post contents of `C_ells_1000.dat`.

Comment: I haven't post the content of C_ells_1000.dat since it is a long file. However it contains a list of 1000 data in scientific notation.

Comment: It would be good if posted a minimal part of this file that is needed to run your code. It might be ill-formatted. Currently it's impossible to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Edit your answer instead of writing it in a comment.

Comment: And what's that `prova.h` thing?

Comment: After running `./prova` I get: `gsl: fprintf_source.c:165: ERROR: fscanf failed. Default GSL error handler invoked. Aborted`. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, I've checked again it works. The problem is when I run the program.

Comment: You got me wrong - I got this error after running the program as I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you declare your variable `Cell` twice. 
Please, replace `gsl_vector * Cell = gsl_vector_alloc(LENGTH_Cell);` with just `Cell = gsl_vector_alloc(LENGTH_Cell);`
Also, do not forget to free your memory correctly with `gsl_vector_free (Cell);` after all your calculations. Modern compilers are smart, however, they do not always catch such minor things (I once spent about a week fixing a similar problem).